# Can anyone solve the line of intersection for the following 2 planes ONLY by solving their equations, and not by finding the planes' crossproduct.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have 2 planes $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and I have to find the line of intersection between those 2 planes. Can anyone do it by solving their equations, because I find it extremely hard due to the fact that there is only 1 variable.

$α\ldots15-z=0$,

$β\ldots3x-z=0$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: **Hint**: Find 2 points $A$ and $B$ such that both satisfy equations of your 2 planes. Then proceed with equation of a line through two points!

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak What if I was to exchange z with t for example at both equations? How would I do that, because I've seen some examples that use that method. I've understood your hint, but I'm still curious about how I could use the swap any variable with t method :)

Comment: To @YousefAhmedZeriouh: I believe I understood your Q. So, usually in the equation of a plane, all 3 variables exists. Since in your problem there are two planes, we are allowed to fix one variable, for an instance we can take $y=0$. Doing that, we will have again the system of two equations, but now with two unknowns.  Such system we will be able to solve in most of cases.

Answer (score 1):

The plane equations are $z=15$ and $z=3x$. Together the give $3x=15$ or $x=5$.